# Erlang wxWidgets how to use validators in custom Dialogs?

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets

I find a definition of call, like this in official Erlang wxWidgets documentation:

```
new(Parent, Id, Options::[Option]) -> wxTextCtrl()

Types:
Parent = wxWindow:wxWindow()
Id = integer()
Option = {value, unicode:chardata()} | {pos, {X::integer(), Y::integer()}} | {size, {W::integer(), H::integer()}} | {style, integer()} | **{validator, wx:wx_object()**}
```

Anybody know, how to use validator?

Comment: what kind of validator you want? Just check the official wxWidgets documentation and adapt to you language

Comment: I cannot find any example of interaction dialog control on custom dialog panel with validator code for Erlang. Can you help me? Official wxWidget's documentation checked by me prior my question =)